# said as an adjective with or without the definite article

Tags: definite-article, participial-adjectives

The Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary gives the following examples of "said":
http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/said

The following is a description of how **said property** [=the property mentioned before] is divided.

by order of the judge of **said court**

It puzzles me why the boldfaced parts do not come with a definite article. Other dictionaries would have "the" with such examples.

Comment: In legal texts, and in non-legal texts written by those who often write legal texts, it is not unusual to find the article absent there.  Articles in legal prose can sound unidiomatic on several fronts. For example, "*a* writing".  "(the) said X" and "(the) aforementioned X" are semantically quite close to a demonstrative, "this X" or "that X".

Comment: What do you mean by "a writing"?

Comment: We don't normally use **writing** as a count noun in the singular with the indefinite article **a**, but that is common in legal texts.  It is a synonym for a document or a writ of some kind, words on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Here **said** is being used to reference or mention something that has been previously mentioned in a document.

Because **said** indicates that the two nouns have already been referred to it therefore acts in a similar way to the use of **the** because the definite article **the** is **also** used to refer to a noun that has already been referred to or mentioned. (the first mention is usually preceded by an indefinite article).

Therefore the use of **the** in the following phrases would be **redundant.**

The said property.
The said court.

**Said** is commonly used in business and legal documents for brevity and and as a conventional practice.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Normally "property" and "court" would require determiners. The first part of your answer seems to suggest that "said" is being used as a determienr ("it therefore acts in a similar way to the use of the"). However, at the end you seem to suggest that the determiner has instead simply been omitted ("Said is commonly used in business and legal documents for brevity"). Can you clarify? (I know that this is an old answer, but I think that this is a good question and deserves a good answer.)

Comment: "Said" can be used with a determiner ("the said transaction") but here it's not (common in legalese). Grammatically it seems to make sense to view "said" as a determiner here because it's functioning to identify a particular thing, but if you assume it's impossible to have 2 determiners before a noun, then "said" can't always be a determiner, so it's a matter of judgment whether it's sometimes a determiner or never a determiner.